# How do you center a VB.NET program on screen before opening it?

Tags: vb.net

Basically, I have this .exe I created with VB.net. Mainly as a little test program. It multiplies 2 numbers and gives the output in a 3rd text box. Nifty little thing. However, I want to center the .exe before it opens so it executes basically in the center of the screen (or monitor).

Like so:
[Multiplier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hT3vc.jpg)

Any help is always appreciated. I'm looking for specific instructions, easy to understand. Thank you.

Comment: Don’t use the accepted answer in the duplicate; set the `StartPosition` from the designer as the second answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line to your your `New()` method:

```
Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, iceman.